# GraphQL JSON schema to Apollo Client Schema

Tags: android, graphql

I have a JSON schema file that looks something like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "queryType": { "name": "Query" },
      "mutationType": { "name": "Mutation" },
      "subscriptionType": null,
      "types": [
        {
          "kind": "OBJECT",
          "name": "Query",
          "description": "",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "planningSearch",
              "description": "",
              "args": [
                {
                  "name": "search",
                  "description": "",
                  "type": {
                    "kind": "NON_NULL",
                    "name": null,
                    "ofType": {
                      "kind": "INPUT_OBJECT",
                      "name": "PlanningSearchInput",
                      "ofType": null
                    }
```

However this won't work in my Android studio project,  I'm following the Apollo Kotlin GraphQL tutorial and the schema they are using and tell you to add to your project looks like this:

```
type Query {
  launches("The number of results to show. Must be >= 1. Default = 20" pageSize: Int, "If you add a cursor here, it will only return results _after_ this cursor" after: String): LaunchConnection!

  launch(id: ID!): Launch

  me: User

  totalTripsBooked: Int
}


type LaunchConnection {
  cursor: String!

  hasMore: Boolean!

  launches: [Launch]!
}

type Launch {
  id: ID!

  site: String

  mission: Mission

  rocket: Rocket

  isBooked: Boolean!
}

type Mission {
  name: String

  missionPatch(size: PatchSize): String
}



type User {
  id: ID!

  email: String!

  profileImage: String

  trips: [Launch]!

  token: String
}

type Mutation {
  bookTrips(launchIds: [ID]!): TripUpdateResponse!

  cancelTrip(launchId: ID!): TripUpdateResponse!

  login(email: String): User
}

type TripUpdateResponse {
  success: Boolean!

  message: String

  launches: [Launch]
}





schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}
```

What can I do to convert the JSON schema to the expected one?

Answer (score 1):

What you are expected is called [GraphQL SDL](https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/lift-off-part1/schema-definition-language-sdl) schema format, and there's some npm tools like [graphql-introspection-json-to-sdl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-introspection-json-to-sdl), [graphql-json-to-sdl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-json-to-sdl) or some [online web site - json2sdl](https://www.json2sdl.com/) can easily to do this.